# material-input not binding to internal objects

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

Using `angular_components` I'm looping through a list of objects to bind to an `material-input` but it's not updating the list of internal objects. There are no reported errors or exceptions in the console. Am I missing something?

I added

```
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:myproject/entity/item/work_item.dart';


@Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
    styleUrls: const['app_component.css'],
    directives: const [
        materialDirectives,
        materialNumberInputDirectives
    ],
    providers: const[materialProviders]
)
class AppComponent
{
    List<WorkItem> workList = new List<WorkItem>();

    void clickToAddItem()
    {
        workList.add(new WorkItem());
    }

}
```

**WorkItem**

```
class WorkItem
{
    int amount = 0;
}
```

**html**

```
        <div
            class="item row"
            *ngFor="let item of workList"
        >
            <material-input
                class="description"
                rows="1"
                label="Description"
                floatingLabel="true"
                multiline
            ></material-input>
            <material-input
                class="amount"
                type="number"
                label="Amount"
                leadingText="$"
                floatingLabel="true"
                [(ngModel)]="item.amount"
            ></material-input>
        </div>
```

**Update:**

After creating many items when I switch between them the objects will randomly populate at random times. There's some kind of delay happening and won't do live updates.

Comment: What Dart and Angular version are you using? I don't see anything wrong in your code. Can you try if a normal `<input>` behaves the same?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I forgot to mention a normal input works just fine. Latest Angular version (3.1) and angular_components

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I'd create a bug report in the components repo.

Comment: do you have repo to clone with repro? Seems you didn't publish the complete example as I do not see how clickToAddItem() happens. You are not using OnPush change detection by any chance?